# Como carregar valores na combobox pelo evento load do form C#

Tags: c#

Estou tentando através deste código:

```
private void frmAdicionarProdutos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string serverName = "localhost";
             string port = "5432";
             string userName = "postgres";
             string password = "adm";
             string databaseName = "GE";
             NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
             string ConnString = null;

             ConnString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                           serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);

            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string cmdCarregar = String.Format("SELECT PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO, PRODUTOS.NOME, PRODUTOS.PRECO FROM PRODUTOS;");
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdCarregar, conn))
                {
                    NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);

                    cbProdutos.DisplayMember = "nome";
                    cbProdutos.ValueMember = "id_produto";
                    cbProdutos.DataSource = dt;
                    conn.Close();
                }     
            }
        }
```

A principio quero só testar desta forma mesmo, depois implemento chamando a classe do banco.

Este código não mostra nada na ComboBox, creio que esqueci de algo.. Pois gostaria de mostrar: Nome do produto + valor dele (concatenado).

Comment: Provavelmente a query deveria ser assim: `string cmdCarregar = String.Format("SELECT ID_PRODUTO, NOME, PRECO FROM PRODUTOS;");`

Comment: Da na mesma, eu testei a query no postgres e me retornava o que precisava, mas na combobox não mostra nada ainda..

Comment: dois pontos, 1 não precisar usar o String.Format . 2 como você mesmo falou precisar [concatenar o PRODUTOS.NOME, PRODUTOS.PRECO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951320/how-to-concatenate-numbers-and-strings-to-format-numbers-in-t-sql) .

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que irá funcionar ao acrescentar o DataBind()

```
cbProdutos.DataBind();
```

Verifique se funciona.

```
private void frmAdicionarProdutos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string serverName = "localhost";
         string port = "5432";
         string userName = "postgres";
         string password = "adm";
         string databaseName = "GE";
         NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
         string ConnString = null;

         ConnString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                       serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);

        using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string cmdCarregar = String.Format("SELECT PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO, PRODUTOS.NOME, PRODUTOS.PRECO FROM PRODUTOS;");
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdCarregar, conn))
            {
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);

                cbProdutos.DisplayMember = "nome";
                cbProdutos.ValueMember = "id_produto";
                cbProdutos.DataSource = dt;
                cbProdutos.DataBind();
                conn.Close();
            }     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não existe pra mim esse `.DataBind()` somente  `.DataBindinds` porém testei e não carregou assim mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu só consigo ver uma causa para o problema: você **não** associou o método `frmAdicionarProdutos_Load` ao evento `Form.Load`

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmAdicionarProdutos_Load);
```

Testei o seu código aqui e o combo carregou certinho.

Comment: Fiz essa alteração também e não carregou mesmo assim.. o load creio que esteja certo.. porque fui nos eventos e o unico load que tem era esse que implementei o código

Comment: Estranho mesmo. Eu testei o seu código e funcionou. Só fiz uma mudança na query para aproveitar uma tabela que eu já tinha. A minha query ficou assim: `string cmdCarregar = String.Format("SELECT \"ID\", \"Descricao\" FROM \"SchemaTeste\".\"TabTeste\";");`

Comment: Outro detalhe: eu estou usando a `Npgsql versão 3.2.5`, Vc chegou a verificar se o código da sua rotina está sendo executado?

Comment: Como posso verificar isso? Seria por `Breakpoint` porém não sei como utiliza-lo neste caso

Comment: Utilizei eles, e deu como `Items.Count = 0`

Comment: Sim, coloque um `Breakpoint` pressionando `F9` sobre uma linha dentro da function. Se a execução não for interrompida, então a sua rotina não está sendo executada.

Comment: Então está sendo executado.. só não da o retorno

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67576/discussion-between-wss-and-fernando).